# Adding 4 UI Labels (linked with 4 sliders) values together

Tags: swift, user-interface, uilabel, uislider

The labels in question can only be integer values 0-8 so I do not know why the compiler  denies every attempt of me adding the four label's values together. This is all in Xcode version 9.0.1. My goal is to have MathValue (I'll lowercase the names later) be the values of all 4 sliders when the "submit" button is clicked.

```
   //
//  ViewController.swift
//  InnovationSS
//
//  Created by AJ Admin on 8/16/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 AJ Admin. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   //The slider that the students will use to input their grades into the app
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriASlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriAValue: UILabel!
    //label is now equal to value of slider
    @IBAction func MathCriAChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriAValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriBSlider: UISlider!

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriBValue: UILabel!

    @IBAction func MathCriBChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriBValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriCSlider: UISlider!

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriCValue: UILabel!
    @IBAction func MathCriCChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriCValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriDSlider: UISlider!

    @IBOutlet weak var MathCriDValue: UILabel!

    @IBAction func MathCriDChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        MathCriDValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var MathValue: UILabel!

    var aValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriAValue.text = "\(aValue)"
        }
    }
    var bValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriBValue.text = "\(bValue)"
        }
    }
    var cValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriCValue.text = "\(cValue)"
        }
    }
    var dValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            MathCriDValue.text = "\(dValue)"
        }
    }
    @IBAction func mathValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
  aValue = Int(sender.value)

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[View the code corresponds with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll45h.png)

Comment: Because compiler doesn't know if the text can be convertible to `Int` or not, so it will return you `Optional` value, which should be `unwrapped` (`!` or `?`) before use.

Comment: Don't post images of code. Paste your code into your question and use the code tag tool. (It indents code blocks by 4 characters, which is the MarkDown way of defining a code block.

Answer (score 0):

> All the outlets are optionals

` you need to unwrap the value then only you can use it.

**Try the following**

```
@IBAction func mathValueChanged(_ sender: UIButton){
 guard let aValue = Int(MathCriAValue.text) , let bValue = Int(MathCriBValue.text) , let cValue = Int(MathCriCValue.text), let dValue = Int(MathCriDValue.text) else { return }
 let Mathvalue = aValue + bValue + cValue + dValue 
}
```

Comment: So I used this exact answer, where in the previous code do I unwrap the labels so this works? I still have the "Value of type 'String?' has no member 'toInt'" error right now.

Comment: @AlanStricklin  Update the answer please verify and let me know

Comment: @AlanStricklin use this ==>
 IBAction func mathValueChanged(_ sender: UIButton){
 guard let aValue = Int(MathCriAValue.text) , let bValue = Int(MathCriBValue.text) , let cValue = Int(MathCriCValue.text), let dValue = Int(MathCriDValue.text) else { return }
 let Mathvalue = aValue + bValue + cValue + dValue 
}

Comment: I did, I had the same error as before, I asked you in the comment directly below where I might unwrap the labels before this part of the code so it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to store your values in labels. Add 4 Int vars to your view controller, `aValue`, `bValue`, `cValue`, and `dValue`.

Have the slider actions change those vars. Add a didSet to each one that changes the label:

```
var aValue: Int {
  didSet {
     mathCriAValue.text = "\(aValue)"
  }
}

@IBAction func mathCriAChanged( sender: UISlider) {
   aValue = Int(sender.value)
}
```

Then if you need the values, you have them as `Int` values already, with no need to convert.

Also, variable names should start with lower-case letters, so `MathCriAValue` should be `mathCriAValue`.

Comment: I got the error: "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'UILabel!'" on the last line of code above (mathCriAValue = Int(sender.value).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The IBAction should change aValue, which in turn will change the text in your label.

Comment: How would that look in code, can you edit your answer. I'm a bit new to app dev...

Comment: My goal is for the 0 next to the Total points label to display the added total of the sliders values, does  this answer work, also I have to find the Sigabrt error in this.